# Can a Mac Studio's RAM be upgraded?

Tags: hardware, memory

Looking at a new upgrade with the Mac Studio and the M1 Max Chip running 32gb of RAM. It indicates that the RAM can be configureable to 64gb. Can I purchase the 32gb option and later on upgrade to 64gb or is the RAM soldered to the logic board? Not finding any solid answers on the question.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer - M-series chips use 'Unified Memory Architecture' -which basically means it's not just soldered, it's actually in the chip itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1_Pro,_M1_Max,_and_M1_Ultra#Memory

Answer (score 2):

The first result of my search for just that question returns what I thought was, indeed, true:

> The short answer is no. If you’ve bought a Mac Studio, you can upgrade
> neither the RAM nor the storage on it. Apple doesn’t make these parts
> accessible to users. So you’re stuck with the configuration you
> initially went for.

This from https://www.xda-developers.com/can-upgrade-ram-storage-mac-studio/ and subsequent results say exactly the same thing.

So buy it with the most RAM you can afford. 'Cause you' ain't upgrading it.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [Mac Studio purchase page](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/mac-studio/10-core-cpu-24-core-gpu-16-core-neural-engine-32gb-memory-512gb#) allows the buyer to select 64GB of RAM, but does not address the question of upgradeability after initial purchase.

Both secondary sources [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Studio) and [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac-studio/specs/mac-studio-m1-max-10-core-cpu-24-core-gpu-2022-specs.html) state clearly that RAM is only upgradeable at the time of purchase.